# Search-ADAccount for user accounts with expiring passwords

Tags: powershell, active-directory, passwords

I've been tasked with finding service accounts (in our shop, that's user accounts starting with 'svc-' in the username) that have expiring passwords. Normally service accounts should not have expiring passwords, so I'm trying to find service accounts incorrectly created so they can be fixed.

I've been using Search-ADAccount and I'm having parameter issues. If I use this:

```
Search-ADAccount -PasswordNeverExpires | Where {$_.SamAccountName -like 'SVC-*'}
```

then I get long lists of results, none of which have expiring passwords. But if I'm including the -PasswordNeverExpires parameter, then I'm filtering out any accounts which *do* have expiring passwords, no?

I've also tried this:

```
Search-ADAccount | Where {$_.SamAccountName -like 'SVC-*' -and $_.PasswordNeverExpires -like 'FALSE' }
```

but I only get an error: "Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters." That sounds like Search-ADAccount requires certain parameters, but I don't see in the help files which parameters are required.

It's counter-intuitive (to me) that Search-ADAccount has a parameter which can search for one Boolean condition (TRUE) but not the other.

Get-ADUser doesn't seem to have any password configuration info.

Comment: Micky, I don't see how that will yield different results from $_.PasswordNeverExpires -like 'FALSE'

Comment: PasswordNeverExpires is a boolean, you are comparing strings :) Another test could be 
$a = $false
$a.ToString() -like 'FALSE' 
which returns True

Comment: Thanks, Micky. I just tried it and received zero results. But if the results are being filtered beforehand with the -PNE parameter, then of course a where search for results will come up empty, no? If I hand you a bag of marbles and ask you to fish out the black marbles, you won't find any if I already pulled the black marbles out.

Comment: What was the exact command you issued? with all Parameters you used

Comment: Search-ADAccount -PasswordNeverExpires | Where-Object { $_.SamAccountName -like 'SVC-*' -and `
    $_.PasswordNeverExpires -eq $false}

Comment: Indeed, with that command you are searching for all accounts which password never expires, so yes, you took all the black marbles out of the equation already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just use get-aduser (need to clean up the filter param, I just banged this together in my head):

```
$adusers = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * | where {$_.PasswordNeverExpires -eq $false}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Trondh. That's it. I first looked at Get-ADUser, but the help files didn't mention anything about the PasswordNeverExpires parameter, and piping a single result into Get-Member didn't reveal any relevant property to search against.

In sum, this is the one-liner that worked:
    Get-ADUser -filter {PasswordNeverExpires -eq $False} | Where {$_.SamAccountName -like 'SVC-*'}

Thanks again.

Comment: Nice! fyi, PasswordNeverExpires is not a parameter, its an attribute on the returned objects.

Comment: How would one learn what those attributes are? I piped one result into Get-Member and found nothing listed involving passwords.

Comment: get-aduser is tricky, since the output object has dynamic attributes. I don't have any tricks for you expect the usual "read the docs". That said, most PowerShell Cmdlets output "static" objects (objects where attributes and methods won't vary) so this one is a bit of an oddity.

Answer (score 0):

did you try $_.PasswordNeverExpires -eq $false?